# Annotating Higher Order Functions in Typescript

Tags: typescript, higher-order-functions

I'm Working with a rather large JS code base, trying to migrate it to typescript and have come across a problem annotating a particular higher order function...

`doStuff()` accepts `fn1` as an argument and wraps it returning a new function that accepts all but the first of argument of `fn1`. sort of like this:

```
const fn1 = (arg_1, arg_2, arg_3, arg_n) => { return 'Hello World' }

const doStuff = (fn) => (...args) => {
    argument1 = getSomeStuffHere()
    return fn(argument1, ...args)
}

const test = doStuff(fn1)
let result = test('arg2', 'arg3', 'arg4')
```

Its worth pointing out there is one `doStuff()` and LOTS of `fnX()` functions with various numbers of arguments of various type combinations that get wrapped up by it. Its important that the functions created by doStuff are correctly typed, "any => any" will not do!

After A LOT of messing about I've finally come up with this:

```
// just for testing simplified example
type MagicObj = {}
const myMagicObject = {}

type Wrapped<T, R> =
    T extends [MagicObj, any, any, any, any] ? (a: T[1], b: T[2], c: T[3], d: T[4]) => R :
    T extends [MagicObj, any, any, any] ? (a: T[1], b: T[2], c: T[3]) => R :
    T extends [MagicObj, any, any] ? (a: T[1], b: T[2]) => R :
    T extends [MagicObj, any] ? (a: T[1]) => R :
    T extends [MagicObj] ? () => R :
    unknown;

const doStuff = <T extends any[], R>(fn: (...args: T) => R): Wrapped<T, R> => (...args) => fn(myMagicObject, ...args)

// testing examples
const fn1 = (obj: MagicObj, p1: string, p2: boolean, p3: number): string => { return 'Hello World' }
const fn2 = (obj: MagicObj, p1: number, p2: string) => { return 'Hello Mars' }
const fn3 = (obj: MagicObj, p1: boolean) => { return 'Hello The Moon' }

const test1 = doStuff(fn1)
// const test1: (a: string, b: boolean, c: number) => string 
let result1 = test1('str', true, 123) 

const test2 = doStuff(fn2)
// const test2: (a: number, b: string) => string
let result2 = test2(123, 'str')

const test3 = doStuff(fn3)
// const test3: (a: boolean) => string
let result3 = test3(true)
```

This seems to sort of work. VSCodes type hinting intellisense witchcraft is showing me what i'd expect/want for the test1, 2, 3 and result variables at the bottom of the example BUT the function returned by doStuff `(...args) => fn(myMagicObject, ...args)`, no matter how I try to annotate it, reports an error along the lines of `Type '(...args: any[]) => any' is not assignable to type 'Wrapped<T, R>'.ts(2322)`

Any ideas how this can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do, I would type `doStuff()` like this instead:

```
const doStuff = <T extends any[], R>(
  fn: (magicObject: MagicObj, ...args: T) => R
): ((...args: T) => R) => (...args) => fn(myMagicObject, ...args);
```

This represents a transformation from any function whose first argument is type `MagicObj` to another function of the same type but with that `MagicObj` parameter removed.  It should work for any number of parameters, by using [rest tuples](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions).

Does that work for you?  Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/PTAECsFcGcBdQGYHsBOpYFM4EsB2BzUabAWwAcAbbBbDAE1AwA8BDcijAWAChYBPMhlABZFvmwBjAPIAjcKAC8oAN6gWALiKwUeQgF8A3DwlJccUCT6jx0uRgnwlqjaABEr0IZ7HT5ukgBlWEgEBEVQAB4AFUYmTFw6aDVcPgBtAF0AGlAAJQA+AAoeUERcTQKSMUlZcHtYTWtquWyAOjaWFHxoTSiASkU83J5e8oK2lo6unv6FQZyZwbH2zugF0oqrKttah1blrt6jbh4QdCxYXVi2SiwfM3gEXABGcIKkOQatmuyyJ804HQEH4AJk0MiQSA4LFwPwAzJpcJASDIMCgRlpAYRZipiqAUBhgihcG4ABIYCgUJCgADqqAodFcRy83BM91KwNe73Anxs31AvwRSJRKBB-20ujWylx+MJxNcZIpVNEKGgjJ4zNZ5kesM5HxEX2a-L+oHBkIw0Ml0oJkCJpPJlNAUQAFkJhBDcGruMy7uZMHAXkp-EEQggCo8nocTmBNfA-bBjQUXADdNkZGCIVCYaAJILkai1smCDwOPB8dBIBR4+E408Cq4Aa5stpIBhsk9gbDI8cWb5Y+cOYHAsFQmHcMCu6cY2c4KDQInc8LU2LMQXxUXuCW8VgK7AB9PdwV27DsvXtK4uz6+3AdYPgyPtRPo739-C5y5TZnV5jiwSt+XKzeL4FM2GBdkAA)

Comment: That works brilliantly, it was the example I needed. Thank you. I also adapted the final 'R' to allow for a variation on the wrapper that if fn returns undefined, will return magicObject instead: so the final R became "(R extends void ? MagicObject : R)". Thanks again.